# Statement requires expression of integer type (int invalid) error with switch statement

Tags: ios, int, switch-statement

I am trying to load an image and label corresponding to the table view row/cell selected by the user. The code appears in my DetailViewController implementation file as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//Create a couple of UIImages
UIImage *jenImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"102_2262.jpg"];
UIImage *jen2Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"102_2288.jpg"];
UIImage *paigeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"102_2332.jpg"];
UIImage *parkerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"102_2379.jpg"];

//Switch UIImages and UILabel based on characterNumber
switch (characterNumber) {
    case 0:
        characterName.text = @"Casual Jen";
        characterPic.image = jenImage;
        self.title = @"Casual Jen";
        break;
    case 1:
        characterName.text = @"Dressed Up Jen";
        characterPic.image = jen2Image;
         self.title = @"Dressed Up Jen";
        break;
    case 2:
        characterName.text = @"Paige";
        characterPic.image = paigeImage;
        self.title = @"Paige";
        break;
    case 3:
        characterName.text = @"Parker";
        characterPic.image = parkerImage;
        self.title = @"Parker";
        break;
    default:
        characterName.text = @"Parker";
        characterPic.image = parkerImage;
        self.title = @"Parker";
        break;
    }
}
```

The switch statement produces the error as described. I have searched for the solution here and elsewhere without success. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the declaration of `characterNumber`?  That's the only thing that's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the data type of `characterNumber` as int.

Comment: It doesn't have to be `int`. It can be any integral type (`char`, `int`, `short`, `long`, `NSInteger`, *etc*.).

Comment: @property int *characterNumber;

Comment: its should be int and not int *.